# react mapDispatchToProps bindActionCreator

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having a difficult time trying to understand mapDispatchToProps

here's a mapDispatchToProps function being used

```
const mapDispatchToProps = () => {
  return {
    addItem: addItem
  };
};
```

So, what's exactly happening here is that the addItem function is now available as a prop to the react component, right?

so, then why do we need to use bindActionCreators and do this

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  /* code change */
  return bindActionCreators({
    addItem: addItem
  }, dispatch);
};
```

what's exactly happening, especially in these lines

```
return bindActionCreators({
        addItem: addItem
      }, dispatch);
```

And why couldnt the previous code without the bindActionCreator work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to "send an action" (aka: dispatching) you need to `dispatch(actionCreator())`

let's assume `addItem` is `function addItem() { return {type: 'addItem', payload: data}; };`

addItem is a function that returns an action. It's an actionCreator (hence: bind actionCreator), but does not dispatch it. You still have to `dispatch` the resulting action.

`mapDispatchToProps` gives you the `dispatch` function which you need to then dispatch that action.

Here's a couple of viable examples:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        addItem: () => dispatch( addItem() ),
        addItemInline: () => dispatch( {type: 'addItem', payload: 'data'} )
    }
};
```

`bindActionCreators` does, in essence, nothing more than this:

```
const bindActionCreators = (actionCreators, dispatch) => {
    let boundActionCreators = {};
    return Object.keys(actionCreators).forEach(key => {
        boundActionCreators[key] = () => {
            dispatch( actionCreators[key]() );
        };
    });
    return boundActionCreators;
};
```

or, more verbose: for every `actionCreator` in the object you pass it, it returns a new function that dispatches the result of the `actionCreator`.

Comment: ok, so what you are saying is that
when we do this
const mapDispatchToProps = () => {
  return {
    addItem: addItem
  };
};

then only additem gets assigned to the function addItem
and when we do 
this.props.addItem   then we get access to the function i.e the action creator only. 
so, it is not callled when we do this.props.addItem
or maybe the correct usage is this.props.addItem() and the action creator creates the action.

But we need to use dispatch to send the created action to the store, right?

Comment: dispatch indeed sends the created action to the store. mapDispatchToProps just puts the assigned keys there as Props to the connected Component. `this.props.addItem()` just creates an action, but does nothing with it. you want to dispatch in `mapDispatchToProps`, which is why you get `dispatch` as a function parameter there.